# How do you get to wave 15 of the pumpkin moon in terraria?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I made an arena, and it can kill everything but I can't make it all the way to round 15. I'm doing it with melee: dragon armor and a mushroom spear. [image]

Comment: Are you using the lava in any way? I would assume any enemy not killed by you directly and instead killed by lava would not count towards the wave score, which would make reaching the 15th wave take more time. Also, are you starting the event at near dawn (as from the screenshot)? Because the event ends at dawn (4.30 AM on the game)...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a silly answer but I found that it was trivial to get to Wave 15 with one other player fighting with me in a simple arena made of a dirt pit with a couple levels of platforms. We both had level-appropriate equipment (we only used our characters while playing on our specific world together) and could effectively kill anything within seconds of it spawning, going through multiple waves every minute.

Everything's easier with a friend!

Answer (score 0):

Try making a 10 block high, 5 blocks across with lava in the middle farm.
And put water candles (you can find them in the dungeon) inside.
And try having a minion with you to kill them faster. That's what worked for me. And also make sure your on hardmode.

Answer (score 0):

In the mobile version of Terraria, it won't show you the percentage of the event. The only way to get to wave 15 is to kill a lot of monsters. Kill everything you find insight. Getting a friend or two to help is a good idea too as it makes it way quicker and easier. Also, pinch your screen so that your avatar is really close as it increases the spawn rates off screen, or at least that's what I thought. Your using Dragon Armor and a Melee weapon, so you shouldn't worry too much about not seeing monsters. Use spawn rate increasing items like the Battle Potion and Water Candle. Hope this helps.